# Nopcommerce security exception

Tags: nopcommerce

When I publish the nopcommerce on the server, I got this error.  My host provides me full trust level.

```
Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed 
    by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission 
    please contact your system administrator or change the application's 
    trust level in the configuration file. 

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. 
    Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified 
    using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[SecurityException: Request failed.]
   Nop.Core.TypeConverterRegistrationStartUpTask.Execute() +0
   Nop.Core.Infrastructure.NopEngine.RunStartupTasks() +487
   Nop.Core.Infrastructure.NopEngine.Initialize(NopConfig config) +48
   Nop.Core.Infrastructure.EngineContext.Initialize(Boolean forceRecreate) +92
   Nop.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +66

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; 
    ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36366
```

how to solve this error?

Comment: did you give proper permissions to folders ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your hosting meets the requirements: [Technology & System Requirements](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=10256757)

Next check whether you done this right: [Installation Guide](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/Installation+guide)

For me this seems like your installation has not enough rights.

According to installation guide you need to give nopCommerce write permission on following directories and files

- \App_Data\
- \bin\
- \Content\
- \Content\Images\
- \Content\Images\Thumbs\
- \Content\Images\Uploaded\
- \Content\files\ExportImport\
- \Plugins\
- \Plugins\bin\
- \Global.asax
- \web.config